# В чём ошибка? Не выводятся одни и те же числа при сортировке

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, матрицы

> Сортировка - 3
> Отсортировать матрицу  n*n  по схеме расположения с помощью алгоритма сортировки из Сорт-1.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


// Создание динамической матрицы
void newMatrix(int**& a, int n)
{
    a = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new int[n];
}

// Вывод матрицы на консоль
void printMatrix(int** a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Заполнение матрицы случайнми числами
void randomMatrix(int** a, int n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            a[i][j] = rand() % (n * n);
}

// копирование из матрицы в массив
int* mass(int** a, int n) {
    int* b = new int[n * n];
    int Ai = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            b[Ai] = (a[i][j]);
            Ai++;
        }
    return b;
    }
}
// Функция сортирует массив а по неубыванию методом подсчета
void sortArray(int* a, int n)
{
    int* c = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //обнуление счётчиков
        c[i] = 0;
    //Подсчет
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (a[i] >= a[j])
                c[i]++;
            else
                c[j]++;
    //Расстановка
    int* b = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[c[i]] = a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }

}
// Фукнция заполняет матрицу по схеме расположения (по строкам)
void fillSnakeMatrix(int** a, int* b, int n)
{
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            for (int j = (n / 2) - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                a[i][j] = k++;
            }

        }

        else
            for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
                a[i][j] = k++;
            }
    }

    for (int j = n / 2; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i][j] = k++;
            }

        }

        else
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                a[i][j] = k++;
            }
    }
}




int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;
    do {
        cout << "Input n" << endl;
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 1 || n > 10);

    int** a = new int*[n];



    newMatrix(a, n);

    randomMatrix(a, n);

    cout << "1 Matrix:" << endl;
    printMatrix(a, n);

    int* b = mass(a, n);
    

    sortArray(b, n*n);


    //int* ar = NULL;


    fillSnakeMatrix(a, b, n);

    cout << "2 Matrix:" << endl;
    printMatrix(a, n);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

} ```
````

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Разгадка в том что `fillSnakeMatrix` не использует аргумент `b`. Вместо этого она заполняет матрицу последовательными целыми числами (`k++`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарий @Stanislav Volodarskiy.
Если рассматривать через подсчет элементов, меньших текущего, то код действительно рабочий.
Ошибка только в одном месте - `return b;` стоит до закрывающей скобки цикла, а должен быть после. Если использовать другой стиль оформления кода, то она сразу же стала бы заметна:

```
// копирование из матрицы в массив
int* mass(int** a, int n) 
{
    int* b = new int[n * n];
    int Ai = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        {
            b[Ai] = (a[i][j]);
            Ai++;
        }
    // return b;  // был здесь - функция заканчивалась после обработки 1 строки матрицы
    }
    return b;  // должен быть здесь
}
```

Comment: Ещё `fillSnakeMatrix` с ошибкой.

Comment: `fillSnakeMatrix()` даже не смотрел - вопрос был ошибка в сортировке

Comment: а как добавить аргумент b если он не является матрицей

Comment: Куда добавить и что Вы хотите с ним делать? Как использовать?

Comment: fillSnakeMatrix не использует аргумент b. я так понимаю ошибка в этом. но я не понимаю как добавить у меня матрица заполняется последовательными целыми числами (k++) а так не должно быть

Comment: А как должно быть?

Comment: получается мы сортируем матрицу в sortArray и в итоге заполняем по рисунку. ошибка в том что числа из sortArray не используются в заполнении. матрица в итоге просто заполняется новыми числами

Comment: Да, так и есть. А по какому рисунку должна заполняться матрица? И чем - числами из сортированного массива?

Comment: рисунок у меня правильный я не знаю как объяснить можно посмотреть. да числами из сортированного массива

Comment: Рисунок неправильный. Сделайте матрицу 4x4  и посмотрите.

Comment: 4 на 4 как раз правильный. проблема в том что во второй матрице числа просто от 0 а не те которые в первой матрице

Comment: Ну если рисунок правильный (хотя и не понятный), то просто в циклах где присваиваете ` a[i][j] = k++;` нужно присваивать ` a[i][j] = b[k++];`

Comment: спасибооо получилось

Comment: :) Здесь спасибо - это принятый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

А они и не должны выводиться. Потому что этот код не имеет никакого отношения к сортировке подсчетом.
Сортировка подсчетом:

- первый проход по массиву - подсчет количества чисел в массиве, в отдельный массив счетчиков, в котором число является индексом
- второй проход - запись в массив чисел, исходя из их количества

А у Вас в `sortArray()` совсем иное:
По алгоритму нужно подсчитывать количество чисел. А у вас подсчитывается что-то не понятное. А с расстановкой тем более непонятно что делается.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (a[i] >= a[j])  // подсчет неизвестно чего
                c[i]++;
            else
                c[j]++;
```

Просто ради интереса выведите в консоль массивы `b[]` и `c[]`и посмотрите на их содержимое!
В общем вся эта функция должна выглядеть гораздо проще:

```
void sortArray(int* a, int n) // n - размерность матрицы
{
    int* c = new int[n*n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) //обнуление счётчиков можно сделать через memset()
        c[i] = 0;
    //Подсчет
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[ a[i] ]++;  // изначальные числа a[i] являются индексами в массиве счетчиков c[i]

    //Расстановка
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n *n; i++) // проход по массиву счетчиков
       for (int j = 0; i < c[i]; j++) // запись c[i] элементов i в массив a
          { 
             a[l] = i;
             l++;
          }
    delete[] c;
}
```

Кроме всего прочего:

- нигде не освобождается ранее выделенная память
- производится множественное копирование матрицы в массив, массивов в матрицу, хотя можно сортировать сразу матрицу.
  Дальше не смотрел.

Comment: Алгоритм ТС считает некоторое число инверсий. Эту логику можно довести до рабочей: если вы знаете сколько в массиве элементов меньше данного, вы знаете на каком месте данный элемент окажется после сортировки. Ругаться в данном случае - не метод. :)

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy А я и не ругаюсь. :) Я описываю косяки в коде. И в комментарии - сортировка методом подсчета.

Comment: Автор не знает терминологии: подсчитывается число элементов меньше данного. Не тестировал, но, возможно, этот код вполне рабочий.